# colours in loops

Tags: color, foreach

How can I get the following by a loop?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=green!20!black] (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
\draw[fill=green!40!black] (0,1) rectangle (1,2);
\draw[fill=green!60!black] (0,2) rectangle (1,3);
\draw[fill=green!80!black] (0,3) rectangle (1,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I thought it would be like this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw[fill=green!{\i*20}!black] (0,{\i-1}) rectangle (1,\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this does not work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!<factor>!` doesn't get sent through the PGF math parser (unlike the coordinates) so you can't put expressions in there.  Fortunately, you can use the `evaluate` key on the `foreach` loop to achieve the same end:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700197/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach[evaluate=\i as \tint using \i*20] \i in {1,2,3,4}
\draw[fill=green!\tint!black] (0,{\i-1}) rectangle (1,\i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Rectangles with varying colour]